# Is this a good approach to mix FB Connect and ASP Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I like to work with asp membership and I need FB integration on a site so I wan't to mix them. Here's what I plan to do:

```
1) Implement method that get data from user FB account (firstname, lastname, username, email)
2) When I get the data, use asp membership CreateUser() method to make user in database
3) Send user temporary password to email
```

I plan to use email from fb as a username so user can login with fb button or by entering their email and password.
**Issues**
- I sometimes receive `null` from fb for user email; if email can be null than I can't use it to make membership user.
- Is this a good way to use both memership and fb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3) Send user temporary password to email
>
> I plan to use email from fb as a username so user can login with fb button or by entering their email and password.

I would not send them a password. What for, that’d be just another piece of sensible information send through the unsafe medium of email.

Instead, if they are logged in to our site with Facebook, I give them the facility to set a password then. If they chose to do so, they can also log in with their username and password – if not, they can still log in via Facebook.

I’ve just checked our database – looks like nearly the only users of those that have used FB login on our site *and* that have a password set are those, whose accounts already existed before we implemented FB login. Of the accounts *created* while loging in via FB, there seem to be but a few that have a password set. And why should they? They have chosen to use FB login to register an account for convenience – why impair that now by setting just another password that wants to be remembered …?

> I sometimes receive null from fb for user email; if email can be null than I can't use it to make membership user.

I’ve heard of this *email being null* problem, though haven’t encountered it myself yet. Apparently this stems from times when an email address was not mandatory to create a FB account, you could also use your phone number.

But in that case, you still have their username, so you could substitute *username*@facebook.com for the missing email address – Facebook has recently set it up so that *every* user now has this email address.

> Is this a good way to use both memership and fb?

I do it pretty much the same way on our site. If someone logs in via FB, I check the database if we already have a connection between the FB userid and a user account in our system; if so, I log that user account in, if not, I create a new one. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it (maybe not the best approach but it works):

1. I create standard memebership tables
2. 2.Add another table where I link users to normal Id's instead of Guids, so I don't have to put guids in url when someone wants to see user profile, also I have field DisplayName, so multiple user can have same DisplayName
3. Use and [OpenID](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) library for C#
4. Addding the following code snippet(this is not finished yet, but it works) to Account Controller:

---

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LoginOpenID(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            using (var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
            {
                var response = openid.GetResponse();

            if (response == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var request = openid.CreateRequest(provider);

                    var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();

                    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);

                    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Alias);

                    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);

                    request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);

                    request.AddCallbackArguments("returnUrl", returnUrl);

                    return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();

                }
                catch (ProtocolException pExp)
                {

                }
                catch (WebException Wexp)
                {

                }
                catch (ArgumentException aexp)
                {
                }
            }

            else
            {
                switch (response.Status)
                {
                    case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                        var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();

                        string alias = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Alias);

                        string email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);

                        string fullname = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))

                            alias = response.ClaimedIdentifier;

                        if (alias.Contains("google"))
                        {
                            Random random = new Random();

                            int randomNumber = random.Next(1000000000);

                            alias = "user" + randomNumber;
                        }

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))

                            email = response.ClaimedIdentifier;

                        //Now see if the user already exists, if not create them

                        if (email.Contains("gmail.com") && Membership.FindUsersByEmail(email).Count > 0)
                        {
                            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email), true);

                            Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
                        }

                        else if (Membership.GetUser(response.ClaimedIdentifier) == null && Membership.FindUsersByEmail(email).Count == 0)
                        {

                            MembershipCreateStatus membershipCreateStatus;

                            string password = GetRandomString(6, 9);

                            MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(response.ClaimedIdentifier.ToString(),

                                password,

                                email,

                                "This is an OpenID account. You should log in with your OpenID.",

                                GetRandomString(5, 7),

                                true,

                                out membershipCreateStatus);

                            if (membershipCreateStatus != MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                            {

                                TempData["message"] = "Unsuccessful creation of Account. " + membershipCreateStatus.ToString();

                                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

                            }

                            if (membershipCreateStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                            {
                                user.Comment = alias;

                                Membership.UpdateUser(user);

                                using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
                                {
                                    Data.UserShortId userShortId = new Data.UserShortId { Guid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey, DisplayName = alias };
                                    context.UserShortIds.InsertOnSubmit(userShortId);
                                    context.SubmitChanges();
                                }
                            }
                            // Use FormsAuthentication to tell ASP.NET that the user is now logged in,  

                            // with the OpenID Claimed Identifier as their username. 

                            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, true);

                            Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, true);

                            Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
                        }

                        break;
                    case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:

                        TempData["message"] = "Login was cancelled at the provider";

                        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

                    case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:

                        TempData["message"] = "Login failed using the provided OpenID identifier";

                        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                }
            }

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
    }

    private static Random random = new Random(46258975);

    public static int GetRandomInteger(int min, int max)
    {
        return random.Next(min, max + 1);
    }

    public static string GetRandomString(int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        int strLength = GetRandomInteger(minLength, maxLength);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            builder.Append(ch);
        }
        return builder.ToString().ToLower();
    }
```

---

When authenticating:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginOpenId", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
           {
                @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])
                <p>Login using:</p>
                <input type="submit" class="login-btn facebook" name="provider" value="http://facebook-openid.appspot.com/" />
                <input type="submit" class="login-btn google" name="provider" value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" />
                <input type="submit" class="login-btn yahoo" name="provider" value="http://me.yahoo.com/" />
           }
```

As you can see this is not finished, Im using Unofficial FB OpenID provider, but you can write case to handle Fb login separatly using OAuth.